# how to find repeating string in a variable having multiple strings in Shell Script?

Tags: shell

Im working with Ksh shell. In my script i have a variable in it which contains mutiple strings, when i echo it it following out put (using echo $serviceList)
xoc.hw.megt.Manager xoc.ssion.ZConionClient xoc.svc.onLifecycle xoc.job.ZSumStateHook xoc.hw.cor.ZBulations xoc.hw.megt.Manager xoc.hw.cor.mmgt.ZMemoro xoc.cot.fdhug

now i have to find is there any string which is repeating if it is repeating then it should give me alert that string is repeated.
e.g. In above example xoc.hw.megt.Manager is repeating.

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/shell-script-to-compare-blocks-of-strings-435211/

Comment: thanks for the link. But im unable to transvers through the variable to get each string separatly.

Comment: serviceList=${serviceList// /$'\n'}
 
for word in $serviceList; do
  echo "$word"
done

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is perhaps to use command **uniq -d**, which will print only duplicate lines, if you can use it like, i.e.

$ my_script | uniq -d

And if you have to implement this within the script itself, then the previous answer gets it done.